# Where are my simulators and how do I install them?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6.1

I cleaned out my personal library in attempt to fix a Xcode behavior bug.
But now I can't see the available SDKs/schema.

I believe the SDKs are with the Xcode bundle, having just download a fresh Xcode from the App Store.

[image]
[image]

So now I only see 'device'.
How to I force Xcode to reveal the simulators?

BTW: I can *see all the simulators* from the SAME Xcode app via my **Guest** account.
     So my own Xcode environment is screwed up.  Is there a remedy?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the Guest to my own account, I noticed that I didn't have any simulated device.

So I did the following: 
1) I copied all the installed simulated devices from my Guest account to my account.

```
$~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
```

2) I noticed that this wasn't enough.  Xcode still could **not** 'see' these devices. 
 So I rebooted in Disk Utility and did a general repair of the entire drive.

Disk Utility noticed some unmapped regions (no doubt my 'erroneous' drives) and the repair fixed it.

Now I got my simulators back.

Comment: It's likely the reboot itself that "fixed" it for you.  The issue was that you deleted ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator while CoreSimulatorService was running.  If you SIGKILLed the process, you would've recovered as well.  In general, don't go trashing process state ;) ... what is the Xcode bug that you were trying to work around?

Comment: I filed a bug report #:19237707; about my cursor popping about as I try to enter code and sometimes the screen doesn't replenish leaving the edit area partially blank until I re-scroll and restore.   The symptom repeats.   I suspect it may have to do with limited memory as mentioned in the report.  However Xcode appears to work normally via my Guest account.  So I suspected something must be wrong with Xcode's local environment.  Hence the cleansing.